# Loop through dictionary values and print subsequently

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop, classification, hierarchy

I am trying to print the following dictionary in a hierarchy format

```
fam_dict{'6081740103':['60817401030000','60817401030100','60817401030200',
'60817401030300','60817401030400','60817401030500','60817401030600']
```

as shown here:

```
60817401030000
    60817401030100
        60817401030200
            60817401030400
                60817401030500
                    60817401030600
```

So far I have the following code which works but I'm having to manually input the i'th index in each line. How can I readjust this code in a recursive format instead of having to count how many lines of code and manually put the index value each time

```
  my_p = node(fam_dict['6081740103'][0], None)
    my_c = node(fam_dict['6081740103'][1], my_p)
    my_d = node(fam_dict['6081740103'][2], my_c)
    my_e = node(fam_dict['6081740103'][4], my_d)
    my_f = node(fam_dict['6081740103'][5], my_e)
    my_g = node(fam_dict['6081740103'][6], my_f)

    print (my_p.name)
    print_children(my_p)
```

Answer (score 5):

You can try this:

```
fam_dict = {'6081740103':['60817401030000','60817401030100','60817401030200',
'60817401030300','60817401030400','60817401030500','60817401030600']}

for i, val in enumerate(fam_dict['6081740103']):
    print(' ' * i * 4 + val)
```

Which outputs your desired hierachy:

```
60817401030000
    60817401030100
        60817401030200
            60817401030300
                60817401030400
                    60817401030500
                        60817401030600
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create a variable that stores the line that you are iterating through, and then increment the variable each time through the loop. You can multiply that variable by \t Which is the tab operator in order to control how many tabs you want. Here is an example:

lines = 0

```
fam_dict = {'6081740103': ['60817401030000','60817401030100','60817401030200',
           '60817401030300','60817401030400','60817401030500','60817401030600']}

for k, val in fam_dict.items():
   for v in val:
       lines += 1
       t = '\t'
       t = t * lines
       print(t + str(v))
```

Here is your output:

```
60817401030000
    60817401030100
        60817401030200
            60817401030300
                60817401030400
                    60817401030500
                        60817401030600
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example:

```
fam_dict = {'6081740103':['60817401030000','60817401030100','60817401030200','60817401030300','60817401030400','60817401030500','60817401030600']}
for k, v in fam_dict.items():
    for i, s in enumerate(v):
        print("%s%s"% ("\t"*i, s))
```

In case you want to make nodes for it:

```
fam_dict = {'6081740103':['60817401030000','60817401030100','60817401030200','60817401030300','60817401030400','60817401030500','60817401030600']}
node_list = []
for k, v in fam_dict.items():
    last_parent = none
    for i, s in enumerate(v):
        print("%s%s"% ("\t"*i, s))
        node_list.append(node(v, last_parent))
        last_parent=node_list[-1]
```

The parent node will be `node_list[0]`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way too.

```
for key in fam_dict.keys():
    for i in range(len(fam_dict[key])):
        print(i*"\t"+ fam_dict[key][i])
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
fam_dict = {'6081740103':['60817401030000','60817401030100','60817401030200',
'60817401030300','60817401030400','60817401030500','60817401030600']}
l = fam_dict['6081740103']
for i in l:
   print(' '*l.index(i)*4+i)
```

Output:

```
60817401030000
    60817401030100
        60817401030200
            60817401030300
                60817401030400
                    60817401030500
                        60817401030600
```